# Given a list of values remove first occurrence

Tags: python, list, function

```
def drop dest(routes,location):
    for i in range(len(routes)):
        if routes[i] == location:
              routes.remove(routes[i])
    return routes
```

I am using a function definition given a list as 
`routes = [(3,2),(2,4),(5,5),(2,4)]`, and say I just want to remove the first occurrence value of `(2,4)`. I am a little confused in how to do this because I do remove the value but I also remove the other value given. Where I just want to remove the first given value.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's simple, use `list.remove`.

```
>>> routes = [(3,2),(2,4),(5,5),(2,4)]
>>> routes.remove((2,4))
>>> routes
[(3, 2), (5, 5), (2, 4)]
```

Comment: I understand that but using my code with the for loop, because my code removes all the value that match it. How do you I fix my code to just remove the first value

Comment: @brian012 because your `for` loop keeps going after the first removal. You could add a `break` to the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

if that is your code and needs to be in a loop and removed only once I would do it like that:

```
def drop_dest(routes,location):
     flag = 1
     for i in range(len(routes)):
          if routes[i] == location and flag == 1:
              routes.remove(routes[i])
              flag = 0
     return routes´
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Just use break statement in the loop. So that the loop stops iterating once it satisfies the if condition for the first time. Using remove() is better but if you want to use loop in your code. This might be the answer.

```
def drop dest(routes,location):
for i in range(len(routes)):
    if routes[i] == location:
          routes.remove(routes[i])
          break
return routes
```